# JavaScript convert object with dynamic property length to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a form (fields are created dynamically with javascript)

```
<input type="text" name="item[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[0][email]" />
<input type="text" name="item[0][address]" />

<input type="text" name="item[1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[1][email]" />
<input type="text" name="item[1][address]" />

<input type="text" name="item[2][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[2][email]" />
<input type="text" name="item[2][address]" />
```

On form submit I get values with javascript function:

```
var obj = serializeObject(form)

function serializeObject(form) {
var o = {};
var a = form.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }      
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

I get an object with dynamic length (3 shown in an example item[0], item[1], item[2]).  Object will always have this number of levels, and "item" is always the same property, only can contain other properties (except name, email, and address shown)

```
var obj = {

item[0][name]:'a',
item[0][email]:'a1',
item[0][address]:'a2',

item[1][name]:'b',
item[1][email]:'b1',
item[1][address]:'b2',

item[2][name]:'c',
item[2][email]:'c1',
item[2][address]:'c2',

}
```

I want to convert it into this format:

```
var arr = [
   {name:'a', email:'a1', address:'a2'},
   {name:'b', email:'b1', address:'b2'},
   {name:'c', email:'c1', address:'c2'}
]
```

What is the best way to convert it (without hardcoding like this):

```
var arr = [];
var o1 = {name:'a', email:'a1', address:'a2'};
var o2 = {name:'b', email:'b1', address:'b2'};
var o3 = {name:'c', email:'c1', address:'c2'};
arr.push(o1);
arr.push(o2);
arr.push(o3);
```

Comment: what is `item`? what do you have? why not take the object literal?

Comment: The first block of code in the question is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question, I get this from php form.

Answer (score 1):

You could take names in the form of a dot separated property string and get the parts and build new objects of it.

```js
function serializeObject(form) {
    const
        matches = form.querySelectorAll("input"),
        result = [];
    
    matches.forEach(input =>
        input.name.split('.').reduce((o, k, i, a) => o[k] ??= i + 1 === a.length ? input.value : {}, result)
    );
    console.log(result);
};

const
    input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('submit', () => serializeObject(input));
```

```html
<form id="input" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" name="0.name" />
  <input type="text" name="0.email" />
  <input type="text" name="0.address" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="1.name" />
  <input type="text" name="1.email" />
  <input type="text" name="1.address" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="2.name" />
  <input type="text" name="2.email" />
  <input type="text" name="2.address" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax doesn't work:

```js
    let obj = {
        item[0][name]:'a'
    }
```

array brackets in key object is not ok
syntax there after is ok:

```js
    let obj = {
        item0name:'a'
    }
```

So regarding your actual syntax, no iteration possible

Comment: I have updated the question, I get this from php form. Thats why keys looks like that.